# Rabbitmq module not found in rsyslog

Tags: rabbitmq, rsyslog

I'm trying to pass my mail.info logs to RabbitMq. According to documentation, rsyslog should have omrabbitmq module, which I'm trying to use. For testing I'm using very simple example:

```
...
module(load="omrabbitmq")
...
action(type="omrabbitmq"
       host="localhost"
       virtual_host="/"
       user="guest"
       password="guest"
       exchange="syslog"
       routing_key="syslog.all")
```

But when I validate the config output is:

`rsyslogd: could not load module 'omrabbitmq', errors: trying to load module /usr/lib/rsyslog/omrabbitmq.so: /usr/lib/rsyslog/omrabbitmq.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory [v8.2004.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2066 ]`

When I'm looking at libs directory there in fact is no rabbitmq module.

My rsyslog version (I performed update from 7 to 8):

```
rsyslogd  8.2004.0 (aka 2020.04) compiled with:
        PLATFORM:                               x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
        PLATFORM (lsb_release -d):
        FEATURE_REGEXP:                         Yes
        GSSAPI Kerberos 5 support:              No
        FEATURE_DEBUG (debug build, slow code): No
        32bit Atomic operations supported:      Yes
        64bit Atomic operations supported:      Yes
        memory allocator:                       system default
        Runtime Instrumentation (slow code):    No
        uuid support:                           Yes
        systemd support:                        No
        Config file:                            /etc/rsyslog.conf
        PID file:                               /var/run/rsyslogd.pid
        Number of Bits in RainerScript integers: 64
```

The question is how can I get rabbit module, is it possible to install it? I found no answer to that.

Comment: Some distributions may provide the module in a separate package (eg on Fedora it is `rsyslog-rabbitmq`), but other distributions may not provide it at all and you will have to find out how to compile it from source.

Comment: I've tried to use ````apt-get install rsyslog-rabbitmq```` and there is no candidate